# WildFly JNDI: What the difference between jboss and global

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, jndi

We have JavaEE specifiaction:
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-spec/JavaEE_Platform_Spec.pdf?AuthParam=1478532325_a9dcd40740691777eb0782e6a8bad14b

In **"EE.5.2.2"** we can see: "**java:global** – Names in this namespace are
shared by all applications deployed in an application server instance."

Also, we have namespace **java:jboss** - https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI%20Reference.html

I can't find information about difference in these namespases and about purpose of java:jboss.

Are they similar or what the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `java:module`, `java:app` and `java:global` namespaces were introduced in Java EE 6 because a platform independent definition of these JNDI scopes did not exist (in particular `java:global`).

Prior to Java EE6, the various vendors defined their own JNDI naming schemes. `java:jboss` is an example of this. These namespaces typically had a global (server or cluster wide) scope.

JBoss AS 7 and newer still support the `java:jboss` namespace in order to provide support for applications that have been ported from older versions of JBoss AS (6.x and earlier).